# Solr can't find library

Tags: java, solr

I'm new to java, but i need to use solr as "full text search" engine...
I was able to install it and run it successfully, but I need to use the "suggester component"

Here is my suggester configuration:

```
<searchComponent name="suggester" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <lst name="spellchecker" >
            <str name="name">suggester</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="field">name</str>
            <!-- <str name="threshold">2</str> -->
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggester">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck"  >true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggester</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="component" >
            <str>suggester</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

I'm running it with command java -jar start.jar ( like [this website](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/doc-files/tutorial.html) ) and get the following error

```
INFO: Closing Searcher@1220b36 main
    fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
    filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
    queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
    documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Aug 9, 2012 5:14:32 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:600)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:332)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:216)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory
'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:394)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:409)
    at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester.init(Suggester.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.inform(SpellCheckComponent.java:598)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:527)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:594)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:378)
    ... 35 more
```

I looked up the class  and I found it in $SOLR_HOME/dist/apache-solr-core-[solr version].jar
so I tried to run Solr with command

```
java -cp $SOLR_HOME/dist/apache-solr-core-3.6.1 -jar start.jar
```

But i got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to customize anything in order to use the Suggester, neither to find that class, which is already included in Solr. I would start with a fresh downloaded Solr 3.6.1 (or  just revert the changes you made). The problem is in your configuration, which contains a line feed between the name of the class and the end of the xml element `</str>`. That's why SOlr can't find that class. Just remove the line feed and everything will work!

Comment: i already check the line feed, and fix it into one line...
but i still got an error...
i did not change anything, i used default configuration...
i just add sugester search component and request handler in **solrconfig.xml** file... just that line i write above...

Comment: I did what you did with a fresh Solr 3.6.1. Copied your configuration, got the error. Removed the line feed, now it works. Don't know what problem you have now. Is it a different error? Have you reverted the changes you made before?

Comment: for detail, i placed the configuration in line 1100...
what that's problem...? i can't seen where is the line feed that you mean...?

edited : i use tomcat as server, rather than jetty

Comment: Well, now you removed the lf from the question, but that was the problem I've found. How can you use tomcat with the command `java -jar start.jar`? That's not what you mentioned in your question. This way is really hard to help you.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understand what you mean... i don't edited question... and i'm sorry again, that time i write the question i used both tomcat and jetty... there is no problem about tomcat or jetty... i try your answer with both server... i already got the answer, the threshold data type must be **float not string**... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

`TSTLookupFactory` should be present in the solr-core jar (at least in version 3.4.0). You can verify it manually (if you're using some other version) by opening the jar file in WinRAR or some other utility capable of opening RAR files and verify that it's in the directory org/apache/solr/spelling/suggest/tst in the jar. If it's not, you may be using an older version of SOLR and you'll have to upgrade.

Then make sure that the solr-core jar is indeed on your classpath (as well as lucene-spellchecker jar and the other solr/lucene jars).

Comment: i found **TSTLookupFactory** on **apache-solr-core-3.6.1.jar**, i found **lucene-spellchecker.jar** too ( in `$SOLR_HOME/example/work/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8983_solr.war__solr__k1kf17/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/` ).. i copy **apache-solr-core-3.6.1.jar** to **lucene-spellchecker.jar** folder ( i rename it to solr-core.jar )... and then i run it...

but i got the same error above